# iOS: Making a build and archive command line tool

Tags: xcode, command-line, build, archive, xcodebuild

I know this subject was many times debated on SO, but I didn't find all the informations.

I'm making an external script that build and archive my project.
I found some good documentation [here](http://nachbaur.com/blog/building-ios-apps-for-over-the-air-adhoc-distribution) and [here](http://blog.octo.com/en/automating-over-the-air-deployment-for-iphone/) but I can't figure out how to get the xcode variables, like `${PROJECT_NAME}`, `${TARGET_SDK}`, and so on.

I also saw this line which could be interesting for sourcing those vars:

```
."$WORKSPACE/autobuild/build.config"
```

but i cannot find any "autobuild" folder nor "build.config" file on my mac.

I have the feeling i missed something straitforward, but i don't know what...

Any idea ?

Comment: There already is such a tool. It's called 'make'.

Comment: funny. I know how to compile, and I would like to get vars stored in the project configuration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you've installed The XCode command line tools (via XCode preferences).

Then, what I use is a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
source "build.cfg"

xcodebuild -target "${XCODE_BUILD_TARGET}" -sdk "${XCODE_BUILD_SDK}" -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${XCODE_BUILD_CODE_SIGN_AUTHORITY}"
EXIT_CODE=$?
if [ ! $EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ];then
  exit $EXIT_CODE
fi

xcrun -sdk "${XCODE_BUILD_SDK}" PackageApplication -v "${XCODE_ABS_BUILD_APP_PATH}" -o "${XCODE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_PATH}" --sign "${XCODE_BUILD_CODE_SIGN_AUTHORITY}" --embed "${XCODE_ABS_PROVISIONING_CERTIFICATE_PATH}"
EXIT_CODE=$?
if [ ! $EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ];then
  exit $EXIT_CODE
fi
```

There is a bunch else I have but that is the key part. Then build.cfg just has the vars above in them:

```
#!/bin/sh
export XCODE_PROJECT_DIR="Builds/iOS"
export XCODE_BUILD_TARGET="Demo-iPhone"
export XCODE_BUILD_SDK="iphoneos"
export XCODE_BUILD_PLIST="Info.plist"
export XCODE_BUILD_APP_NAME="demo.app"
export XCODE_BUILD_APP_DIR="build"
export XCODE_BUILD_CODE_SIGN_AUTHORITY="iPhone Distribution: ABC"
export XCODE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_IPA_FILENAME="demo.ipa"
export XCODE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_IPA_DIR="build/release"
export XCODE_ARCHIVE_PROVISIONING_CERTIFICATE="demo_adhoc.mobileprovision"
...
```

Comment: But the point is: how can i get `XCODE_ABS_BUILD_APP_PATH` automatically?

Comment: I don't think there is a tool for that. ANd even if there was, many projects have multiple targets, sdks, certificates, etc. So you would still need to put your choice somewhere. We do parse the XCode project files to edit settings from the shell, but as above I use a config file hand-made for each project.